# After the window closes, how to open in 10 seconds

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Dialog opens after 10 seconds, not continuous, I want to wait 10 seconds again after closing

How to ı Make

1. First opens in 10 seconds
2. I click on the close button after 5 seconds
3. Second, so it opens again after 5 seconds
4. I want 10 seconds to start again after I turn it off

The code is here

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    final Handler h = new Handler();
    final int delay = 10000;

    h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            //do something
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
            dialog.setTitle("Title...");

            Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);

            dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();

                }
            });

            dialog.show();
            h.postDelayed(this, delay);
        }
    }, delay);
```

Comment: You have added delay in your code.

Comment: it is not clear what you want. The English is too bad.

Comment: you want delay after dialog is close too?

Comment: @SunishaSindhu that's all

Comment: @Vlad open a dialog again ten seconds after it has closed

Comment: @AliAhsan exactly

Comment: @AliAhsan Can i tell turkish

Answer (score 1):

Wait 10 seconds before cancelling like this

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    final Handler h = new Handler();
    final int delay = 10000;

    h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            //do something
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
            dialog.setTitle("Title...");

            Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);

            dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                     h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                      public void run() {
                         //this method will execute with a delay of after 10 seconds
                         dialog.dismiss();
                      }, delay);
                }
            });

            dialog.show();
            h.postDelayed(this, delay);
        }
    }, delay);
```

Comment: @HamzaKAVAK show the error, the code jinesh shared make sense

Comment: I copied it under setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); but  Last lines inappropriate.

There is nothing in the project

Answer (score 1):

First declare one global varialbe for Handler to update the UI control from Thread, like below

```
//time for 60 seconds

int time = 0;

Handler mHandler = new Handler();


 public void showDialog(){


    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {


                            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
                            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
                            dialog.setTitle("Title...");

                            Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);

                            dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                 if(time<=60){
                                 time += 10;
                                 showDialog();

                                 }
                                }
                            });

                            dialog.show();

                        }
                    });
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: Abi yapmak istediğim olay şu ; 10 saniyede bir dialog açmak istiyorum. Bu işlem tamam. Dialogu kapatıyorum. istediğim olay dialog açıldığı anda saniye dursun. Ben ne zaman kapatırsam yeniden 10 saniye saysın. :) İngilizce anlatamadım :)

Comment: This code works continuously 10 seconds. I want you to wait 10 seconds again after I turn it off

Comment: okay so you want 10 second delay after you close the first one and then show dialog again for 10 second?

Comment: Yes, I will use it as an advertisement. Will come to a continuous screen in 60 seconds

Comment: How can i do it

Comment: I am sorry :(  
15:18:20 Application started then Dialog opened in 15:18:30. I closed it in 15:18:38. Dialog opened again in : 15:18:40.

Comment: I want it to stop for 10 seconds after I turn it off

Comment: I've updated the code in under. Application not working

Comment: what the issue you are having?

Comment: Android Emulator : testApp stopped working. Could you write the code in whole class?

Comment: No faulty record in event log. How can ı do ?

Comment: NO.  Can you share all of the code, all the classes

Comment: Now, 16:32 Instant Run applied code changes and restarted the app.
16:32 Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

Answer (score 1):

I did it this way, but the application was stopped

`public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Handler mHandler = new Handler();`

```
 Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}






public void showDialog(){

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {



                            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
                            dialog.setTitle("Title...");

                            Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);

                            dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                    showDialog();

                                }
                            });

                            dialog.show();

                        }
                    });
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
}
```